# Wordpress plugin upload timeout - nginx

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress plugin, locally, it works perfectly, however, when I try to upload to an online test environment (same as the production one), I get a timeout error.

We used a nginx server, I tried to change timeout by adding a timeout.conf file, but, I still have the same problem.

Access logs:

`2019/09/09 20:42:58 [error] 30692#30692: *56472 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream`

I use composer in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your php script those lines

```
ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);
```

Comment: does your localhost is also a `nginx` server?